# Jdbc Postgresql is not executing the query

Tags: java, android, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to connect my android app to my postgresql database through jdbc, the login goes well but when i try run the query explotes and give me this error:

```
11-24 11:03:14.966: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
11-24 11:03:14.966: E/AndroidRuntime(673):  at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:283)
```

This is the code of the function that make the connection:

```
public void save_info(Element plate_info){
         String retval = "";
         try {
             Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             retval = e.toString();
         }
         String url = "jdbc:postgresql://test.com:5432/test_db?user=adsfsdfasd&password=2222222";
         Connection conn;
         try {
             DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
             conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
             Statement st = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO order_tbl (custumer, _name, additional, ingredients_) VALUES('adsfasdf','asdfasdfasdf', 'asdfasdfasd', 'asdfasdfasdf', 'dasfasdf')");
             while(rs.next()) {
                 retval = rs.getString(1);
             }
             rs.close();
             st.close();
             conn.close();
             System.out.println(retval);
         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             retval = e.toString();

         }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `executeUpdate`, not `executeQuery`

```
int numRowsAffected = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO order_tbl (custumer, _name, additional, ingredients_) VALUES('adsfasdf','asdfasdfasdf', 'asdfasdfasd', 'asdfasdfasdf', 'dasfasdf')");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need.

```
DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(5);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("INSERT INTO order_tbl (custumer, _name, additional, ingredients_) VALUES('adsfasdf','asdfasdfasdf', 'asdfasdfasd', 'asdfasdfasdf', 'dasfasdf')");
```

Here's a quick tutorial on how to use SQL Insert http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zto0PovkbKo

Comment: It works for Java with out Android, but when i try to do it from the android is not working.